# Grid button shadowing over column name

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I have created a grid which contains some columns and a button on the far right. Using this button, the user can show / hide selected grid columns. The problem is that the rightmost column name is partially hidden by this button. [image]

As can be seen in the following picture. Is there a method to make it so that either:

1. The button is moved slightly to the right, even outside the border of the grid
2. The rightmost column name is moved to not be underneath the button

If possible, I would like to implement the first solution, as the column names can be reorganized by the user and the solution would have to be dynamic.

Comment: Is this the button you get from the hideable columns or something you
have conjured up yourself?  If in doubyt, please add the code.

Comment: Are you creating the button along these lines? https://cookbook.vaadin.com/grid-column-toggle

Comment: Oh, never mind, you had tagged this for Vaadin 8. The Vaadin 8 Grid has a built-in button for this purpose, have you styled it to make it look like that or done some other modifications?

Comment: I have solved this by creating a block of code that adds a CSS styling to the rightmost column upon the grid creation, column reorder and column visibility event. The CSS styling adds padding to the rightmost column header, so that it is not overshadowed by the button.